# jQuery match height for element throughout site and not just per page instance of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a row of "cards" throughout my site and am using jquery match height plugin to create equal heights. This works on each page fine and makes equal size cards regardless of content. What I want to do is make the cards equal height on ALL pages of the site regardless of content in the cards. Is there way to use the plugin for this without setting a min or max height explicitly?

html:

```
  <div class="col-md-4 col-card>
          <div class="l-col-card”>
              <!--icon row-->
              <div class="image-container">
                  <img src="/img/cta.png" alt="" class="img-responsive">
              </div>
              <div class="card-content-column">
              <!--title row-->
              <h2 class="card__title">Test Cards</h2>
              <!--content-->
              <p class="card__text">Test Text</p>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

jquery:

```
  $('.col-card').matchHeight({
  byRow: 0
  });
```

Comment: How in the world would you know the max height on any page?

Comment: not the page, the card

Comment: You just can't. A different page is not loaded till you click on it. If it's not loaded, there's no way to get the height of the "future" element

Comment: I know it is not the page. The issue what you want to do is basically impossible You would need to preload every page so the cards render and inspect the height and apply it.

Comment: I figured that was just being optimistic someone knew a way :)....thanks for the input